# What is the use of HttpURLConnection class's setDoOutput & setDoInput methods

Tags: java, android

I am calling **POST** webservice with below line of code.

I am not clear with `connection.setDoOutput( true );` and `connection.setDoInput( true );`

Can you please elaborate me purpose of this code ?

Can I use same code with **GET** or not ?

```
URL url = new URL( "http://xxxxxx.com" );
HttpURLConnection connection = ( HttpURLConnection ) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
connection.setDoOutput( true );
connection.setDoInput( true );
connection.setUseCaches( false );
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`setDoOutput(true)` is used with POST to allow sending a body via the connection:

```
OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
os.write(body);
os.flush();
os.close();
```

`setDoInput(true)` is used to fetch the response and is `true` by default.

When using a different method e.g. GET, you have nothing to pass to the connection, so an `OutputStream` is not necessary.