# url returns true json but android HttpURLConnection return false

Tags: android

I have a Https url that return a json like this:

```
{success:true, success_msg:'Register/Unregister was accomplished successfully',desc:'',redirect:false}
```

When i want to get the url response using HttpURLConnection in android, it returns this json:

```
{success:false, title:'Traffic Authentication Page',fail_msg:'Register/Unregister was failed',desc:''}
```

Here is http utils class. I used from doGet(String url) method

```
public class HttpUtil {
    static {
        try {
            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = { new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {

                    return null;
                }

                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                        String authType) {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                        String authType) {
                }
            } };
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

            HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
                public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                    return true;
                }
            };
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());

            HttpsURLConnection
                    .setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
        } catch (Exception localException) {
        }
    }

    private static HttpUtil httpUtil;

    HttpUtil() {
    }

    public static HttpUtil getHttpUtil() {
        if (httpUtil == null)
            httpUtil = new HttpUtil();

        return httpUtil;
    }

    public String doGet(String url) throws Exception {

        // configure the SSLContext with a TrustManager

        URL urlObj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        String line;
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try
        {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }
        } catch(Exception localException) {

        }
        reader.close();
        conn.disconnect();

        return buffer.toString();
    }
}
```

when i log url it seems correct. i produce url in asynctask doInBackground by params that get from user. this url return true json but send this request via android return false json. why it returns false? Please help me.

Comment: The message clearly shows that there is some failure maybe Authentication  failed. Double check the API and see if you missing any header information.

Answer (score 0):

The true and false values in Json are set by 0 and 1
and using `Boolean.valueOf("1") => return true` to convert it to real value

Answer (score 0):

My solution solved. I just delete  `conn.setDoOutput(true);` because in GET method there is no output stream.

This question helped me: [What is the use of HttpURLConnection class's setDoOutput & setDoInput methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29558759)